# log42.xml is not picked up when running JMH benchmark from test directory

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2

I have a Gradle task to run a JMH benchmark:

```
task benchmark(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn compileTestJava
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.example.Benchmark"
}
```

`Benchmark` is just the entry point for JMH and is located at `src\test\java\com\example` (written in Kotlin, but that shouldn't matter here):

```
object Benchmark {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {        
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args)
    }
}
```

To not distort my benchmark I want to suppress logging to the console. Therefore I created a `log4j2.xml` config file under `src\test\resources`.

In my `log42.xml` I commented out every reference to the console appender and I even commented out the appender itself. But I still get log messages on the console, what means that my Log4j config isn't effective and the default config is used instead. This is the [fallback of Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration).

If I add the following block to the above `main` method, everything seems to be correct:

```
val log4Url = javaClass.classLoader.getResource("log4j2.xml")
val log4JConfigPath = Paths.get(log4Url.toURI())
println("classpath: " + log4JConfigPath.toAbsolutePath())
```

The `log4j2.xml` exists where I expect it to be (`build\resources\test\log4j2.xml`). The behavior is the same with the file name `log4j2-test-xml`). The config file from `src\main\resources` is also ignored.

I'm using Gradle 4.7 if this is of any relevance.

What do I have to do to make Log4j use the config file form my test resources directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a side effect of incorrect dependency management. The benchmark is part of a Spring Boot application and Spring Boot comes with Logback logging by default. If you want to use Log4J instead, you have to [exclude Logback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging) explicitly. I did so, but forgot it with a new dependency so Logback came back.

The fix is to exclude Logback (brought through `spring-boot-starter-logging`) once and for all with this Gradle config:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
```